# Android studio shows very specific incorrect errors with JavaPoet library

Tags: android-studio, gradle, ide, syntax-error, javapoet

I've written an annotation processor using JavaPoet library and included it as a Java Library module to my project. It compiles and works fine. The problem is - Android Studio inline compiler shows me errors that shouldn't be there.

1. For some reason it doesn't recognize ellipsis in parameters 
   [image: first error]
2. The same as above.
   [image]
3. It shows that there's no method writeTo that takes Filer type as a parameter, even though there's clearly one when you choose Go To > Declaration option. And as I mentioned - it compiles fine. 
   [image]

I have already tried:

1. **Cleaning and rebuilding project** - didn't work
2. **Syncing gradle several times** - didn't work
3. **Refreshing gradle project** - didn't work
4. **Using File > Invalidate Cache/Restart option** - didn't work
5. **Deleting .gradle and .idea folders and syncing once again** - didn't work
6. **Deleting my Java Library module from project and from disk and creating it anew with the same classes** - didn't work either

Always the same three errors, so I am quite at loss here. I have to mention that **this problem occurred once I downgraded JavaPoet version from 1.12.1 to 1.9.0** (Java 7 compability turned out to be crucial for my app version, so higher Java 8 versions are out of question).
My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc2'
    implementation 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc2'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.9.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
```

It's not a deal-breaker, but it's distracting and annoying. Do you have any idea of what may be the reason for such behavior?

Comment: This may help you, https://github.com/square/javapoet/issues/491#issuecomment-275943134

Comment: Thank you a lot. It finally worked with the advice presented in the link you shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still don't understand what might be the reason, the errors disappeared, once I included the processor module as a project **in my main app module**, not as a jar.
Basically, I changed this line:

```
annotationProcessor files('../migrationprocessor/build/libs/migrationprocessor.jar')
```

To this line:

```
annotationProcessor project(':migrationprocessor')
```